# Centering text, x coordinate not respected

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I modified TextToPDF class to detect some tag in the content file.
When tag center is found, text is centered.

That don't work correctly, X coordinate don't seem respected

when i display x: coordonate, i get: 
0

0

18.861816

2.9138184

238.31181

9.933823

68.68582

10.347824

40.14981

In the pdf generated, line 6 is supposed to start before line 5, but it start after.

238.31181 > 9.933823 but pdfbox seem to say 9.933823 > 238.31181

result of the genereated file
[image]

This string is put in a StringReader for createPDFFromText parameter.

```
String rawText = "Children's heart surgery has been suspended with immediate effect at a hospital which is embroiled in a long-running row over the future of paediatric cardiac services in England. \n "
    + "#CENTER#The decision to stop congenital heart surgery at Leeds General Infirmary comes just a day after the High Court quashed plans by the NHS to close its children's unit after ruling the consultation process was flawed.\n "
    + "It follows concerns raised about patients' care including allegations the hospital was avoiding referring children for complex and life-saving treatment at another centre in Newcastle.\n "
    + "Leeds Teaching Hospitals NHS Trust said the temporary measure was being taken to allow an internal review to be conducted following consultation with the Care Quality Commission (CQC).";
```

Code

```
public PDDocument createPDFFromText( Reader text ) throws IOException
{
    PDDocument doc = null;
    PDSimpleFont font = PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN;
    int fontSize = 12;
    boolean isCentered = false;
    try
    {

        final int margin = 40;
        float height = font.getFontDescriptor().getFontBoundingBox().getHeight()/1000;

        //calculate font height and increase by 5 percent.
        height = height*fontSize*1.05f;
        doc = new PDDocument();
        BufferedReader data = new BufferedReader( text );
        String nextLine = null;
        PDPage page = new PDPage();
        PDPageContentStream contentStream = null;
        float y = -1;
        float maxStringLength = page.getMediaBox().getWidth() - 2*margin;

        // There is a special case of creating a PDF document from an empty string.
        boolean textIsEmpty = true;

        while( (nextLine = data.readLine()) != null )
        {

            // The input text is nonEmpty. New pages will be created and added
            // to the PDF document as they are needed, depending on the length of
            // the text.
            textIsEmpty = false;

            String[] lineWords = nextLine.trim().split( " " );
            int lineIndex = 0;
            while( lineIndex < lineWords.length )
            {
                StringBuffer nextLineToDraw = new StringBuffer();
                float lengthIfUsingNextWord = 0;
                do
                {
                    nextLineToDraw.append( lineWords[lineIndex] );
                    nextLineToDraw.append( " " );
                    lineIndex++;
                    if( lineIndex < lineWords.length )
                    {
                        String lineWithNextWord = nextLineToDraw.toString() + lineWords[lineIndex];
                        lengthIfUsingNextWord =
                            (font.getStringWidth( lineWithNextWord )/1000) * fontSize;
                    }
                }
                while( lineIndex < lineWords.length &&
                       lengthIfUsingNextWord < maxStringLength );
                if( y < margin )
                {
                    // We have crossed the end-of-page boundary and need to extend the
                    // document by another page.
                    page = new PDPage();
                    doc.addPage( page );
                    if( contentStream != null )
                    {
                        contentStream.endText();
                        contentStream.close();
                    }
                    contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
                    contentStream.setFont( font, fontSize );
                    contentStream.beginText();
                    y = page.getMediaBox().getHeight() - margin + height;
                    contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(
                        margin, y );

                }
                //System.out.println( "Drawing string at " + x + "," + y );

                if( contentStream == null )
                {
                    throw new IOException( "Error:Expected non-null content stream." );
                }

                String txt = nextLineToDraw.toString();

                if ( txt.indexOf( "#CENTER#" ) != -1 || isCentered )
                {
                    txt = nextLineToDraw.toString().replaceAll( "#CENTER#", "" );

                    PDRectangle pageSize = page.findMediaBox();
                    float stringWidth = font.getStringWidth( txt );
                    float xPosition = ( pageSize.getWidth() - ( 2 * margin ) - ( stringWidth * fontSize ) / 1000f ) / 2f;

                    System.out.println( xPosition );

                    contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount( xPosition, -height );
                    isCentered = true;
                }
                else
                {
                                            System.out.println( 0);
                    contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount( 0, -height );
                }

                y -= height;
                contentStream.drawString( nextLineToDraw.toString() );
            }
        }
        if (textIsEmpty)
        {
            doc.addPage(page);
        }

        if( contentStream != null )
        {
            contentStream.endText();
            contentStream.close();
        }
    }
    catch( IOException io )
    {
        if( doc != null )
        {
            doc.close();
        }
        throw io;
    }
    return doc;
}
```

File result is available here: http://filebin.ca/br6slMSfOR6/testUnitairePdf.pdf
Like you can see, text is not centered correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is (just like @GaborSch guessed in his comment to his answer) that

```
contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount()
```

works relative to the last line, not relative to some fixed margin.

*In detail:*

The `PDPageContentStream` method `moveTextPositionByAmount` is documented as:

```
/**
 * The Td operator.
 * @param x The x coordinate.
 * @param y The y coordinate.
 * @throws IOException If there is an error writing to the stream.
 */
public void moveTextPositionByAmount( float x, float y ) throws IOException
```

The **Td** operator in turn is documented as:

> **tx ty Td** Move to the start of the next line, offset from the start of the current line by (tx, ty). tx and ty shall denote numbers expressed in unscaled text space units. More precisely, this operator shall perform these assignments:

[image]

*(cf. the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1:2008](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf), section 9.4.2 "Text-Positioning Operators")*

Therefore, you'll have to remember the `xPosition` value used and

- either right after the line

  ```
  contentStream.drawString( nextLineToDraw.toString() );
  ```

  insert

  ```
  contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount( -xPosition, 0 );
  ```

  if the line was centered;
- or wait until determining the `moveTextPositionByAmount` arguments for the next line of text and substract this former `xPosition` value from the new x value then.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are trying to insert all the text block into each other.

You call `contentStream.begintText()` in the loop, but you call `contentStream.endText()` only once, outside the whole loop.

I'm not familiar with `TextToPDF`, just a guess. But it seems to me that the next indent is correct, it is only rendered relatively to the previous block, **because the prevoius block has not been closed properly.**

I recommend to pair the `beginText()`s with `endText()`s, that will help.

Comment: my code it's only the part about centering text.
close inside the loop is to manage end page.

in debug mode, i put system out around begin and end text. i get

beginText
0

0

18.861816

2.9138184

238.31181

9.933823

68.68582

10.347824

40.14981

endText

Comment: Next guess: `contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount()` will move the text relatively from the last position, not relatively from the left edge.